# MongoDB only uses one thread

Tags: mongodb

MacOS with mongodb-community@4.2 (installed using brew)

**TLDR: MongoDB is only running as one process, seemingly not taking advantage of the 7 other available CPU cores.**

I'm running a simple NodeJS application with PM2, making use of all 8 of my CPU cores.

Using Apache Benchmark, I try to stress-test the application for retrieving data. The endpoint I am hitting retrieves data from my MongoDB database. (Only reading, no write operations are performed).

During the stress-test I get these results:

1. There are 8 active NodeJS processes
2. There is only 1 active MongoDB process
3. CPU usage indicates that MongoDB is the bottleneck. How can I ensure that MongoDB takes advantage of more cores?

Screenshot from TOP:
[image: 8 node processes, only 1 mongodb]

Why is MongoDB only making use of 1 process/core?

Can I increase performance by configuring it to use more than one process/core?

Some additional information, `serverStatus()` run during the stress-test: [image: connections]

Comment: The fact that it's using over 100% CPU suggests it's using more than 1 CPU. It's also likely that because you have multiple node processes using the majority of the CPU, you're starving the mongo node of CPU resource. On the top command you'll be able to see the CPU load in the top right, if this is above 8 then you have more load than CPUs.

Comment: Also, to make the most of MongoDB, then you need to ensure you have the appropriate indexes. What is your `read` command, and what indexes do you have to satisfy that read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB (as [any database](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127257/is-multiple-mysqld-processes-for-1-mysql-server-is-normal)) works with single process to **ensure consistency**, it uses locking and other [concurrency control](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-concurrency-control) measures to prevent multiple clients from modifying the same piece of data simultaneously.

### MongoDB Performance

> In some cases, the number of connections between the applications and the database can overwhelm the ability of the server to handle requests. The following fields in the serverStatus document can provide insight:
>
> - connections is a container for the following two fields:
>
>   - `connections.current` the total number of current clients connected to the database instance.
>   - `connections.available` the total number of unused connections available for new clients.
>
> If there are numerous concurrent application requests, the database may have trouble keeping up with demand. If this is the case, then you will need to increase the capacity of your deployment.
>
> For read-heavy applications, **increase the size of your replica set and distribute read operations to secondary members**.
>
> For write-heavy applications, deploy sharding and add one or more shards to a sharded cluster to distribute load among mongod instances.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/analyzing-mongodb-performance/#number-of-connections

Comment: Can you check if your driver has [read preference: secondary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/#secondary)? Also, you need to enable your secondary nodes `myset:SECONDARY> rs.slaveOk()`

Comment: Thank you, once the replica set was properly configured I was able to spread the read-load across the secondaries by using readPreference ``secondaryPreferred``. Note: I had a situation where one of the secondaries was stuck in "recovering". This lead to a significant slowdown.